# cc_grpc_library for bazel 0.5.1 fails due to mandatory "files_to_run" provider missing

Tags: grpc, bazel

I am  trying to build a cc_grpc_library defined in grpc/bazel/cc_grpc_library.bzl like below:

```
cc_grpc_library(
    name = "test",
    srcs = [ "test.proto" ],
    deps = [],
    proto_only = False,
    well_known_protos = "@com_google_protobuf//:well_known_protos",
    generate_mock = False,
    use_external = True)
```

but it fails due to

```
'@grpc//:grpc_cpp_plugin' does not have mandatory provider 'files_to_run'.
```

I am using bazel 0.5.1 and latest from grpc repository. No local modifications to either bazel or grpc.

See [this simple example](https://github.com/fardream/grpc_bazel_test).

Also to note, bazel 0.4.5 works fine.

Comment: Do you have any local modifications? `@grpc//:grpc_proto_plugin` is defined in [`//:BUILD`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/65b2ff9418b0cd97ff7d8bda2409ea6c7937b9a0/BUILD#L206), and the [`grpc_proto_plugin` is a macro wrapping a cc_binary](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/65b2ff9418b0cd97ff7d8bda2409ea6c7937b9a0/bazel/grpc_build_system.bzl#L46) which should have a `files_to_run` provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow this was fun debugging :) I think you could file an issue for this, it's a regular bug. So this works with bazel 0.4.5, it doesn't with bazel 0.5.0 and 0.5.1, and it works again with bazel@HEAD. It was fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/629eeccbd1bc0af3a2e682a1cf154a543d07c2ca), then broken, and then fixed "by accident" by [this commit](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/211a3ba2303c1df97383c810e17a031106c7271b).

Now bazel@HEAD won't build the project, but it's seems like it's an error in the project itself, not a bazel bug anymore.

Comment: Looks like 0.5.2 fixed the issue. Thanks